# Javascript google chart settings

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the following chart. And I want both the units next to the chart and on the chart to have an empty " " as a thousands separator. And I want the numbers to be followed by the units, for example "$100,000". Any advice?

[http://jsfiddle.net/fvL726r9/][1]

```
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


                <div class="Container50" id="piechart" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"/>

                        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                        function drawChart() {

                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Genre', 'Vk', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Sta', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Va', { role: 'annotation' } ],
                                ['Ps', 360000, 'Vk', 82000, 'Sta', 200000, 'Vy'],
                                ['Ds', 360000, 'Vk', 82000, 'Sta', 200000, 'Vy']

                            ]);

                            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

                            view.setColumns([0,
                                1, {
                                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                                        return dt.getValue(row, 1);
                                    },
                                    type: "number",
                                    role: "annotation",

                                },
                                3, {
                                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                                        return dt.getValue(row, 3);
                                    },
                                    type: "number",
                                    role: "annotation"
                                },
                                5, {
                                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                                        return dt.getValue(row, 5);
                                    },
                                    type: "number",
                                    role: "annotation"
                                },

                            ]);

                            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                                groupingSymbol: ' ',
                                suffix: ' Kč',
                                fractionDigits: 0,
                                pattern: '# Kč'

                            });
                            formatter.format(view, 5);

                            var options = {
                                title: '',
                                isStacked: true,
                                //pieSliceText: 'value',
                                legend: { position: 'right'},
                                chartArea: {
                                    left: "10%",
                                    top: "4%",
                                    height: "92%",
                                    width: "70%"
                                },
                                colors: ['#3366CC','#DC3912','#23C228', '#000000'],
                            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                            chart.draw(view, options);

                            document.getElementById("j_idt26:chart").value = chart.getImageURI();
                        }
```

Comment: Your question is expected to contain the least amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue described (a [mre]) ***in the body of your question*** - external links change/break over time and reduce value for future visitors to this question. [ask]

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Can you please confirm that *all* this code you've pasted here represents a complete and succinct [mre]? I would expect that the inclusion of some of this code to demonstrate your issue is rather unnecessary; it also does not seem this code is runnable without additional code context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, the formatter will not work on a data view.
so you will need to format the data table, prior to building the view.

next, there is not a *pattern* that will allow the space character to be used as a separator.
remove the *pattern* option from the formatter.

```
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ' ',
    suffix: ' Kč',
    fractionDigits: 0,
    prefix: '$'
  });
```

and you need to format all the number columns...

```
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  formatter.format(data, 2);
  formatter.format(data, 3);
```

next, in order to format the annotations, you will need to use the formatter's `formatValue` method.
and change the type of annotations to `'string'`

```
  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1));  // <-- use formatValue
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation",
    },
```

and since you are adding the annotations in the data view,
the annotation columns can be removed from the data table.

finally, since the *pattern* will not work,
the only way to format the v-axis labels is to provide your own custom ticks.

the `ticks` option expects an array of values.
in this case, we will need to use object notation,
to provide both the value (`v:`) of the tick,
and the formatted value (`f:`)

```
ticks: [{v: 0, v: '0'}, {v: 100000, f: '100 000 Kč'}, {v: 200000, f: '200 000 Kč'}, ...]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Genre', 'Vk', 'Sta', 'Va'],
    ['Ps', 360000, 82000, 200000],
    ['Ds', 360000, 82000, 200000]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    groupingSymbol: ' ',
    suffix: ' Kč',
    fractionDigits: 0,
    prefix: '$'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  formatter.format(data, 2);
  formatter.format(data, 3);


  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1));
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation",
    },
    2, {
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 2));
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    3, {
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 3));
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
    isStacked: true,
    //pieSliceText: 'value',
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: "12%",
      top: "4%",
      height: "92%",
      width: "70%"
    },
    colors: ['#3366CC', '#DC3912', '#23C228', '#000000'],
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [{v: 0, v: '0'}, {v: 100000, f: '$100 000 Kč'}, {v: 200000, f: '$200 000 Kč'}, {v: 300000, f: '$300 000 Kč'}, {v: 400000, f: '$400 000 Kč'}, {v: 500000, f: '$500 000 Kč'}, {v: 600000, f: '$600 000 Kč'}, {v: 700000, f: '$700 000 Kč'}]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(view, options);

  document.getElementById("j_idt26:chart").value = chart.getImageURI();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="Container50" id="piechart" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" />
```

Comment: Nice! Can you change the currency to dollars? That was asked in the question. Besides that the answer seems to be correct.

Comment: sure, simple, must have missed that. add `prefix: '$'` to the formatter. and add `'$'` to the ticks. also, you'll need to increase `chartArea.left`, else the labels will wrap.

Comment: I'm not the asker. I just visited the page, read the question and your answer, found your answer to be correct and uploaded it. Then left a friendly note of criticism of how the answer can be improved.

Comment: ha! didn't even notice, thanks @LajosArpad!